# Idea behind probability integral transform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be continuous random variable. CDF of $X$ at a given point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $F_X (x) = \mathbb{P} (X \leq x)$ which gives us a probability of an event that randomly choosen $X$ (from a predefined distribution) is less or equal than given $x$.

In probability integral transform we define $Y = F_X(X) $ and then we proof that $Y \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$. But what is the idea behind $Y$? Can we see this as $F_X(X) = \mathbb{P} (X \leq X) $ and does it mean that both $X$'s on LHS and RHS of the inequality $X\leq X$ are randomly taken from a predefined distribution? And taking two random $X$'s and comparing them (and measuring probability of such comparison) gives us uniform distribution no matter what the distribution of $X$ is (until it's continuous distribution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the probability space be $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mu)$. We have that $F_X:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
$$F_X(x)=\mu(\{\xi \in \Omega:X(\xi)\leq x\})=\mu_X((-\infty,x])$$
where $\mu_X$ is the probability distribution of $X$. In general, $F_X$ is always Borel measurable for measurable $X$:
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}:F_X(x)< a\}=\begin{cases}
\emptyset & a \leq 0 \\
(-\infty,\inf\{x \in \mathbb{R}:F_X(x)\geq a\}) & 0<a\leq 1\\
\mathbb{R} & a > 1
\end{cases}\Bigg\}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
Therefore the random variable $(F_X \circ X):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
$$(F_X\circ X)(\omega)=F_X(X(\omega))=\mu(\{\xi \in \Omega:X(\xi)\leq X(\omega)\})$$
is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable and well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to see that $Y=F_X(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]\,:$
$$
P(Y<y)=P(F_X(X)<y)=P(X<F^{-1}_X(y))=(F_X\circ F^{-1}_X)(y)=y\,.
$$
Voila ! The simple 'idea behind' this $Y$ is that it can be used as a starting point to construct (simulate) a random variable $X$ of any given distribution $F_X(x)\,:$
Just simulate a uniform $Y$ and define
$$
X:=F_X^{-1}(Y)\,.
$$